# Kafka fips: BCFIPS not working with upgrade to JAVA11

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, fips

I have a kafka cluster running in FIPS mode with below configuration.

```
Brokers: 3, Zookeeper Nodes: 3
Kafka: 2.0.0, Scala: 2.12
Zookeeper: 3.4.14
Java - 8
bc-fips - 1.0.1
```

This cluster is running fine and is in a healthy state.

Currently we have upgraded Kafka(2.4.0) and Java(11) versions, after which FIPS cluster is unable to load bc-fips library and start kafka. New cluster configuration:

```
Brokers: 3, Zookeeper Nodes: 3
Kafka: 2.4.0, Scala: 2.12
Zookeeper: 3.4.14
Java - 11
bc-fips - 1.0.2
```

With the analysis so far, the problem seems to be with **loading bc-fips jar** with new JAVA version(11), as java doc says:

- JDK9 onwards the support for adding external jars via **jre/lib/ext** is removed.
- The ability to pass extra parameters to the Security Providers on load time is removed

So when I am starting the kafka service its failing with below error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DEFAULT SecureRandom not available
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:85)
    at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:753)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:394)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addDataPlaneProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.addDataPlaneProcessors(SocketServer.scala:278)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:241)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:238)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:121)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:263)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DEFAULT SecureRandom not available
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createSecureRandom(SslEngineBuilder.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.<init>(SslEngineBuilder.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:154)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DEFAULT SecureRandom not available
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance(SecureRandom.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createSecureRandom(SslEngineBuilder.java:124)
    ... 21 more
[2020-05-18 11:59:39,646] INFO [KafkaServer id=48] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

**Note**: As said above the same configuration works with java-8.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got this working with below setup

**Java:** 11.0.7

**BCFIPS:** bc-fips-1.0.2.jar

Add the bcfips jar in kafka lib directory: **<-kafka-root-directory->/libs/bc-fips-1.0.2.jar**

And start the kafka server, it will load bcfips jar.